# http and ssh not working for github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am only starting to use github. i used gitbash and cloned my first repository using http it worked and i made changes added new files and commit but push is not working  So i switched to ssh generated key ,added it image of checking connection :
[image]

but even after that it doesn't work
image shows orgin and errors :
[image]

I tried lot of tutorials and forum and git help but I can't fix that.am student so don't feel bad if my question is stupid.
is there is a chance for such connection problems related to isp or my network.

```
git push orgin master
fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

Comment: Try "origin" instead of "orgin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a small typo:

`origin` instead of `orgin`
[image]

Comment: Ohhh that was my error sorry for being stupid. I spent entire night in searching instead of watching the problem clearly. But that was good I managed understand complex things like https and ssh--      Thanks a lot guys really appreciate your patience